# Meaning of "were not taking any chances with something"

Tags: phrase-meaning

https://www.nytimes.com/2018/10/24/nyregion/cnn-time-warner-bomb-nyc.html

> But people across the country were not **taking any chances with**
>   suspicious packages after six pipe bombs were sent to prominent
>   Democrats on the East Coast.

What does it mean?

1. people were not having the chance to get a suspicious packages.
2. people were anxious about every packages they received.

Comment: Have you heard of the expression **to take no chances**? If not, follow this link: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20no%20chances

Comment: @MichaelRybkin You mean "not take chance" is same with "take no chance"?

Comment: Yes, it's just an alternative grammatical form of that expression. **I don't have any pens** is the same thing as saying **I have no pens**. Same meaning, but just slightly different grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Taking a chance** or **to take a chance** means choosing to do something that has a risk of failure or of negative consequences.

**Not taking any chances** or **to take no chances** means to avoid anything that has a risk of failure or of negative consequences (or at least to try to do so).

In this context it means that people will be extra careful of suspicious packages because of the circumstances, whereas normally people might be more willing to assume that suspicious packages are just mislabeled, delivered to the wrong address, etc.